# Node Red Azure IotEdge module always fails

Tags: raspberry-pi3, node-red, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I have installed node-red module on my Azure IoT edge device. However, it always fails to run.
I used the following [tutorial](https://github.com/iotblackbelt/noderededgemodule)
I am using Raspberry Pi 3 with ARM 32v7 processor. Yes, I have set IoT Hub requirement from the tutorial. Other examples on my IoT edge device work properly except the node red module.

The logs are provided.
[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of text, they are really hard to read, impossible for people who use screen readers and you can't search for then. Please post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it

Answer (score 0):

That failure has nothing to do with the azure node.

The failure is to do with having write permission to the `/data` directory. Assuming it's running in a docker container and you have mounted a volume into the container at the `/data` point then you need to make sure that the UID 1000 has write permissions to the volume/mount point.

UID is the default user mapped to the `node-red` inside the container.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the root cause. Do you know how to make sure that the UID 1000 has write permissions?

Comment: That entirely depends on the OS and filesystem and path you are mounting as the volume.